# Using MapView on non-"Google Market"/non-"Google featured" phones

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, google-play

Is it possible to use the MapView to build on GMaps-based  apps without having Google Market and the other Google tools installed?

Do i need to have a custom ROM on such phones with that Google tools?

Are there some other possibilities to use Maps and a MapView-like-thing?

Especially some Tablet devices like Notion Ink Adam , Advent Vega und Point of View Tegra lack this Google Tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the device does not have Google Maps, you cannot create `MapView`-related apps.

However, bear in mind that there is a lightly-documented `android:required` attribute on the `<uses-library>` tag. If you set that to be `false`, your app should still load on `MapView`-less devices. You can use `Class.`forName`()` to see if the `MapView` class exists -- if it does not, you can substitute something else (e.g., WebView with the Web version of Google Maps, OpenStreetMap) or disable the map features entirely.